# Template Type != Deduced type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm attempting to give a friendly name to a type as a template typename because I need to use the name in a few places within the function. The type is being deduced based on the number of other template arguments in the parameter pack, as shown below:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename ... TArgs, typename Functor = std::function< std::conditional_t< sizeof...(TArgs) == 0, int (), int (TArgs...) > > >
void DoStuff(const Functor & func, TArgs ... args) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(TArgs) == 0)
        assert(typeid(Functor).hash_code() == typeid(std::function<int ()>).hash_code());
    else
        assert(typeid(Functor).hash_code() == typeid(std::function<int (TArgs...)>).hash_code());
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    DoStuff([] () { return 5; });
    DoStuff([] (int a) { return a; });

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine, but both assertions fail because the alias `Functor` is not actually a `std::function<>`. On the other hand, if I change the code to repeat the definition of `Functor` in the `typeid` calls it works perfectly, like below:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename ... TArgs, typename Functor = std::function< std::conditional_t< sizeof...(TArgs) == 0, int (), int (TArgs...) > > >
void DoStuff(const Functor & func, TArgs ... args) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(TArgs) == 0)
        assert(typeid(std::function< std::conditional_t< sizeof...(TArgs) == 0, int (), int (TArgs...) > >).hash_code() == typeid(std::function<int ()>).hash_code());
    else
        assert(typeid(std::function< std::conditional_t< sizeof...(TArgs) == 0, int (), int (TArgs...) > >).hash_code() == typeid(std::function<int (TArgs...)>).hash_code());
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    DoStuff([] () { return 5; });
    DoStuff([] (int a) { return a; });

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the first declaration (using the `typname Functor = ...`) incorrect? Is there a different way to make that alias? Note that in answering the second question, it is OK if the solution is a const expression, the examples are only not `constexpr` because of the use of `typeid`.

Comment: @Jarod42 that still fails both assertions :/

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you think you need this alias?

Comment: @Barry I want to eliminate the need to repeat the definition in the 3 places that I need it. I would rather make the definition once and use the alias everywhere else

Comment: @Howard The definition of what? For what? In order to do what? What is the *actual problem*? It's easy to answer why your asserts fail, but I don't even know why they're there and what you're trying to test so I can't really answer how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not asking for another solution to the problem. I am only asking what is wrong with the way it is written. Why is that not what I expect it to be? It is surprising to me that it does not work as written, and i would like to know why.

Comment: That's not an alias.  It's a default template type argument.   When you pass in at least one argument to this function,  the default is ignored and it uses the type deduction rules.  Also, your use of conditional is not necessary here.  Finally, what are your assertions attempting to acomplish?

Comment: @DaveS the use of conditional allows me to pass lambdas directly as r-values without explicitly converting to `std::function` first. And you are right, I misspoke since alias defines an explicit thing, I intended it to mean simply a name which refers to the type. The assertions in the example were only there to show what my expected behavior was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the first declaration (using the `typename Functor = ...`) incorrect?

You're providing a default type for the template parameter `Functor`. But the default type is only used if the type is not otherwise specified or deduced. In this case, template deduction will deduce `Functor` in both cases to be whatever the unique type of the lambda is that it is invoked with (while `Args...` deduces as an empty pack).

This is similar to default function arguments not being used when they are provided.

I'm not sure what your `assert()`s are supposed to accomplish, but if you're checking types you should use `static_assert`.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense now. I didn't know that it would attempt to deduce a default template parameter. I was under the incorrect assumption it was only not the default when it was specified. The asserts are only in that code to show that it did not do what I intended it to do, and to shed some light on what I expected it to be. Can the code above be rewritten to alias the `std::function<>` type to a name?

Comment: @Howard You mean like `using T = int;`?

Comment: precisely like the `using` statement. I don't entirely understand from the documentation if I could use it such that the created alias is only scoped to the function and can still be used to name the parameter type